# Export multiple .csv files into .txt files in one go

Tags: python, pandas, csv, text

I have multiple .csv files with different names like ATUL.csv, ISEC.csv, XYZ.csv and so on... Every file has similar data format mentioned below:

```
datetime              symbol    open    high    low    close    volume

2005-03-10 09:15:00   NSE:ATUL  85.59   89.00   85.19   86.84   73582
2005-03-11 09:15:00   NSE:ATUL  89.44   89.80   85.50   85.94   153945
2005-03-14 09:15:00   NSE:ATUL  86.90   88.75   84.00   84.65   73539
2005-03-15 09:15:00   NSE:ATUL  85.00   85.94   82.00   82.40   79053
```

I want to create a new .txt for every .csv file with formatting given below:

1. remove 'symbol' column
2. remove header row i.e. datetime|symbol|open.....
3. change 'datetime' column date and time format to YYYYMMDD
4. separate each column with ";"

Desired format sample given below for understanding.

```
20050310;85.59;89.00;85.19;86.84;73582
20050311;89.44;89.80;85.50;85.94;153945
20050314;86.90;88.75;84.00;84.65;73539
20050315;85.00;85.94;82.00;82.40;79053
```

I am trying below code to get my output

```
 import pandas as pd
 data = pd.read_csv('ATUL.csv')
 data.drop('symbol', inplace=True, axis=1)
 data['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['datetime']).dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
 data.to_csv('output.txt', sep=';', header=None, index=False)
```

Above code is working great but its creating/converting one file at a time, my problem is that above with above code I am able to convert only one file at once, I have more than 500 files that I have to update on daily basis.

Is there any way or code that I could convert all my .csv files to text files with desired formatting (as motioned above code)

Comment: Put the code you have into a function that has two parameters, the input and output file names. Write a loop that applies this function to all the .csv filenames is a folder.

Comment: Thank you so much @martineau, As I am very new to python, it would be a great help if you could elaborate/explain with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's code that does exactly what I suggested in my earlier [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238647/export-multiple-csv-files-into-txt-files-in-one-go#comment127629596_72238647). 
It makes use of the built-in [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module to simplify processing.

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path


def export_csv(input_filepath, output_filepath):
    """Reformat input file and save result to the given output file path."""
    data = pd.read_csv(input_filepath)
    data.drop('symbol', inplace=True, axis=1)
    data['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['datetime']).dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    data.to_csv(output_filepath, sep=';', header=None, index=False)


folderpath = Path('path/to/csv/files/folder').resolve()
new_suffix = '.txt'

# Convert all .csv files in given folder.
for input_filepath in folderpath.glob('*.csv'):

    # Output file path is the same as the input file except it has a different
    # extension.
    output_filepath = input_filepath.with_suffix(new_suffix)

    export_csv(input_filepath, output_filepath)  # Convert the file.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Python expert, there is my solution for your problem.

First pack all your file in one single directory, then use `os` module to browse into it.

**EDIT**

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

path = "path/to/directory/with/csv"

with os.scandir(path) as it:
    for entry in it:
        if entry.is_file() and entry.name.endswith(".csv"): #  Treat only csv files 
             # Convert csv to txt with your code here
             data = pd.read_csv(entry.name)
             data.drop('symbol', inplace=True, axis=1)
             data['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['datetime']).dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
             data.to_csv('output.txt', sep=';', header=None, index=False)
```

This should work if you replace path value with the actual path to directory with your files on your computer.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions, but it is not working in my case

Comment: What kind of error do you have ?

Comment: I dont know where to put my code with your suggested code, my code is import pandas as pd
 data = pd.read_csv('ATUL.csv')
 data.drop('symbol', inplace=True, axis=1)
 data['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['datetime']).dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
 data.to_csv('output.txt', sep=';', header=None, index=False)

Comment: I have put your code in mine to make it work for you. Now you just have to copy paste this code and replace path value with correct path. (eg : "C:/user/documents/files_to_convert/" or "." if your python file is in the same directory with your csv files)

Comment: You're welcome. If it works, don't forget to make this issue solved.